# iOS show recursive loading animation until completion of initialisation code block, then show the last animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, loading

I want to show loading animation while I am doing some initialisation. So I want to spin my `(UIImageView*)_LogoImage` until my initialisation will be completed. Then, after initialisation will be finished, I want to scale my _LogoImage. So, all this things begins from `viewDidAppear`, where I am calling beginLoading: method.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self beginLoading];
}
```

Here, I am starting my spin animation. Assume, I am doing some initialisation in the next two code lines, I changed them to make a thread sleep to make a similar behaviour of my initialisation code. Then I am calling stopSpin: method to make the next half circle and to do my last scaling animation.

```
-(void)beginLoading{
    [self startSpin];
    [self sleepAction:3.0f];
    [self sleepAction:1.0f];
    [self stopSpin];
}
-(void)sleepAction:(float)sleepTime{
    NSLog(@"SleepTime:[%f]",sleepTime);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:sleepTime];
}
```

Here's my spinning code, which I am calling recursively until my BOOL refreshAnimating is Equal to YES. if not - running the last scaling animation

```
-(void)startSpin{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         _LogoImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                                               delay:0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                          animations:^{

                                              _LogoImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                              if (refreshAnimating) {
                                                  [self startSpin];
                                              }else{
                                                  [self refreshFinished];
                                              }

                                          }];
                     }];
}
-(void)stopSpin{
    refreshAnimating = NO;
}
-(void)refreshFinished{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [_LogoImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)];
    }];
}
```

The problem is that my animation is not running, until the last initialisation code line completes. And after completion - I can see only the last animation. I was trying to put some code performing in the background and main thread, but I didn't run the way I want.
The rotation animation should start when the view appears, and continue until my initialisation code complete - then I want to see my last scale animation, which will indicate that my initialisation is completed. 
Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ersin Sezgin said, all animations run on main thread. 
So now, I am doing initialisation in background with completion block handler, which is forcing stopSpin: after initialisation completes.
Here's some code block. For better readability there's typedef of block.

```
typedef void(^OperationSuccessCompletionHandler)(BOOL success);
```

in .m file

```
-(void)sleepAction:(OperationSuccessCompletionHandler)success{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // We are doing initialisation here
    BOOL isOperationSuccess = YES // Assume initialisation was successful
    success(isOperationSuccess);
 });
}
```

So now we can do this in another way

```
-(void)beginLoading{
    [self startSpin];
    [self sleepAction:^(BOOL success){
        [self sleepAction:^(BOOL success){
            [self stopSpin];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All animations run on main thread and if you use sleep, it blocks your animations(main thread). Instead you can use a library like: [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) please feel free to ask further questions.

**Edit**

```
-(void)startSpin{
        _LogoImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
         delay:0
         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
         animations:^{
               _LogoImage.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);              
         }
             completion:nil];
}
```

Can you try this. I think that is what are trying to do.